# Only match on first key when geting data from a table

Tags: lua

Im storing keys in a table like this:

```
d = { ["Rune_Test"] = "78100;Iconmisc0002", ["Sword_Test"] = "78097;Iconsword11" }
```

This table is stored in my ItemHandler.lua file.

```
local ItemHandler = {} 

d = {}

function ItemHandler:LoadData(_data)
    d = _data
end

function ItemHandler:GetData()
    return d
end

function SaveItem(nId, Name, Sprite)
    d[trim(string.gsub(Name, " ", "_"))] = nId .. ";" .. Sprite
end
```

My main lua file is Central.lua and it looks something like this:

```
function Central:OnRestore(eLevel, tData)
    DataItems = tData.items or {}
    ItemHandler:LoadData(tData.items or {})
end

function Central:OnSave(eLevel)
local tSave =
{
    items = ItemHandler.GetData()
}
return tSave
end
```

My xml save file currently look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document>
<N K="items" T="t">
    <N K="Rune_Test" T="s" V="78100;Iconmisc0002"/>
    <N K="Sword_Test" T="s" V="78097;Iconsword11"/>
</N>
```

Im using a function like this to look for a specifik key:

```
function ItemHandler:CheckItem(iName)
    if d[iName] ~= nil then
        Print("Got it!")
    end
end
```

The problem I'm having tho is that I only get a match on the first key in the xml document.

```
print(d.Rune_Test)
= 78100;Iconmisc0002
e
print(d.Sword_Test)
= nil
```

I guess I'm just missing out on something really simple here. I'm a big noob when it comes to LUA just started learning it a couple of days ago. :) But I have C# knowledge so it isn't all jibbberish :P

Comment: You have `Print("Got it!")` in the code, but the output does not show it for either of the keys you access. is this the intended behaviour? Also, which API are you using? Which environment is it?

Comment: Thanks for your comment :) Yeah I kinda put this all together and edited some but I still have the same issue with only geting the first line of the xml back. Im coding an addon for the game Wildstar and it's API11. I was very very tired when writing this post yesterday sorry if it's kinda messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you skip the loading/saving stuff, it works:

```
d = { ["Rune_Test"]  = "78100;Iconmisc0002", 
      ["Sword_Test"] = "78097;Iconsword11" }

print(d.Rune_Test)
print(d.Sword_Test)
```

That prints:

```
78100;Iconmisc0002
78097;Iconsword11
```

Therefore what you are loading from XML is not what you think you are.

---

Try printing the table after loading it, eg.

```
for k, v in pairs (d) do
  print ("key=", k, "value=", v)
end -- for
```

You *should* see:

```
key= Rune_Test value= 78100;Iconmisc0002
key= Sword_Test value= 78097;Iconsword11
```